# how to read complete response from server in java script without doing ajax call

Tags: javascript

how to read complete response from server in java script without doing ajax call.

when we download file we get http response which include Content type and content length in Response header.I want read Content type and content length of http response sent by server without making an ajax call or using XMLHttpRequest object.

please suggest if you have any alternative.

Comment: your question does not make sense? from what I can figure the only way to do this is to echo the content type & length from server side and read it from javascript, although the application for this seems questionable

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What's wrong with using AJAX? Are you running the JavaScript in the browser or somewhere else? Do you want just the content type+length or do you really want to download everything?

Comment: `ajax` is more of an optimal way than pure `js`...mind telling whats hindering you from using ajax??

Comment: My problem is when i click on download button it make a request to server to download the file and in response i get downloadable file along with response header. since i want to read response that i already received i can't use XMLHTTRequest or Ajax to read already received response.Please suggest how i can read already received response.

Answer (score 0):

Before some more experienced member responds... :

Simply put....i don't think its possible...`javascript` is client side language....

so you need something to ensure that server response *is read and converted* to your client side language!!!

For that you need either ajax, catching the response or removing `JS` altogether out of equation doing everything in some server scripting language!!

Comment: I agree--I'm not sure this can be done using WebSocket I/O either.  You might be able to do it in NodeJS, but not in the browser.